# Get the value of a div

Tags: javascript

Helllo, I'm having a div like this:

```
<div>1+1</div>
```

How can I get these '1+1' to the javascript and calculate them to '2'?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to somehow identify this div, e.g

```
<div id="div-with-expression">1+1</div>
```

And code will be like:

```
console.log(eval(document.getElementById('div-with-expression').innerText));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use innerHTML property of element by javascript to extract the value:

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML
```

and then use eval() method to evaluate the math expression:

```
var exp=document.getElementById("div").innerHTML;
alert(eval(exp));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`:

```
var equation = getElementById(IdOfDiv).innerHTML;
var result = eval(equation);
```

Comment: innerHTML is a bad idea because of possible entities

Answer (score 0):

Well, You could use the Javascript eval() func:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

But, eval functions can introduce malicious code into your environment.

I'm not sure as to what your purpose to start with and what your assumptions are for that input but here's another way to go about it with regex although it's more complicated:

```
var myRegexp = /(\d+)(\+)(\d+)/;
var match = myRegexp.exec("1+1");
// parseInt(match[0]) == 1 ,as an Int
// match[1] = '+', you could figure what operand this is with 'if else' conditions
// parseInt(match[2]) == 1 ,as an Int
```